# Creating a standard queue of pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, queue

Say I have a queue of integers,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    int firstValToBePushed = 1;

    queue<int> CheckoutLine;

    CheckoutLine.push(firstValeToBePushed);

    cout << CheckoutLine.front();

    return 0;
}
```

How can I do essentially the same thing using a queue which holds pointers to integers as opposed to integers like it currently does above.  I plan on making a loop to make more than one value but this is just a more simple example.

Thanks,

Comment: What is your ultimate requirement for needing a pointer to integer?
As far as definitions go, `queue<int*> CheckoutLine;` is what you want.

Comment: As @KarthikT said, it highly depends on your task. The question is, what you plan to use pointers for? Do you want to dynamically allocate and delete integers stored in the queue? Remember, size of int is usually equal to size of pointer, so you don't waste any space by passing integers directly.

Comment: I eventually want to take these pointers which will be referencing objects of a class, store them in the queue then have the ability to move them out of the queue to a list. I used integers in the example above because they are more simple for the sake of this question.

Comment: @Joe The type of object is relatively irrelevant. You don’t need pointers for that either, and from your description so far you should *not* use pointers here.

Answer (score 5):

If that's for lifetime management, then:

```
std::queue<std::shared_ptr<int>> CheckoutLine;
CheckoutLine.push(std::make_shared<int>(firstValeToBePushed))
```

If your queue is kind like a proxy, and someone else actually owns the lifetime of the objects, then definitely:

```
std::queue<std::reference_wrapper<int>> CheckoutLine;
CheckoutLine.push(firstValeToBePushed)
```

If you do not expose the queue anywhere and it's internal, *then storing pointers is fine*, as others suggested.

However, **NEVER EVER** expose to a client a collection of pointers, that's the worst thing one can do as you leave the burden of managing the lifetime on them, and that's the messier on collections.

Of course for primitive types or PODs, just copying is fine, no need to store pointers. Move semantics makes it easy even for non-PODs, unless you have some tricky construction or you object cannot implement move semantics.

`#include <functional>` for `std::reference_wrapper` and `#include <memory>` for `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` and friends. I'll assume you have access to a modern compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a loop for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main() {

queue<int*> theQueue;
char c = 'n';

while (c == 'n') {
  cout << "Enter \'n\' to add a new number to queue ( \'q\' to quit):";
  cin >> c;
  if ( c == 'q') {
    break;
  }
  else {
    int num;
    cout << "Enter an integer and press return: ";
    cin >> num;
    theQueue.push(new int(num));
  }
}

while( !theQueue.empty() ) {
  cout << theQueue.front() << ": " << *theQueue.front() << endl;
      delete theQueue.front();
  theQueue.pop();
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int  value = 1337;

int* firstValeToBePushed = &value;


queue<int*> CheckoutLine;



CheckoutLine.push(firstValeToBePushed);


cout << *(CheckoutLine.front()) << "is at " << CheckoutLine.front();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: I know this is just for illustration purposes, but storing pointers to stack-based objects in a container is always suspect.

Comment: @Mat Arguably better than storing raw pointers to heap-based objects. Both are equivalent as long as the pointer doesn’t confer ownership.

Comment: yes of but it show how to use it. shure you can replace `int* firstValToBePushed = &value;` with `int* firstValToBePushed = malloc(sizeof(int)); *firstValToBePushed = 1337;` but why to complicate this for illustration

Comment: @kenny `malloc` has no place in C++ (and the code wouldn’t compiler without a cast).

Comment: @Konrad: why? "At worst", raw pointers to heap-based objects will lead to leaks. Pointers to stack can lead to stack corruption which is, IMO, generally harder to debug (and extremely Heisenbug-prone).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph yes of couse im writing to much code in c ^^ 
in c++ use `int* firstValToBePushed = new int;` and also a `delete` at the end to avoid memory leaks

Comment: @Mat Dunno. Both are easy to catch with appropriate tools. I was concerned with the *valid* use of such pointers, and a non-owning pointer (to either heap- or stack-based memory) is totally fine. What *isn’t* fine is a raw pointer that owns memory. If I see that in modern C++ code, I will immediately consider it a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand, maybe you want do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int firstValueToBePushed = 1;

    queue<int *> CheckoutLine;

    CheckoutLine.push(new int(firstValueToBePushed));

    cout << *CheckoutLine.front() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: … aand you’re leaking memory.

Comment: Would it be possible to fix this memory leak by using a deconstructor?

Comment: In my code, you have to create a pointer who receive "CheckoutLine.front()", and do a delete on this pointer after the cout. The destrutor is call when you use delete on a pointer or automatically for static variable.

Comment: @JoeElder No, a *destructor* wouldn't do in this case. You would have to make sure you delete all the elements in the queue before leaving the scope (in this case, the main function).

Comment: I did a test using a custom class with a destructor instead of int type. And when I called `pop` it automatically called the destructor which I wasn't expecting that. I tough `pop` would only delete the pointer to that custom class and I had to delete the pointer before calling pop. Can anyone confirm my finding?